# A question for old unix gurus or simply older SVR4 users: backup output

Tags: backup, svr4

On SYSVR4(AT&T 2.1) i want to make a backup full of /dev/root

i did this

```
bkreg -a varfull -o /:/dev/root -c demand -m ffile -d disk -t mytb1
```

varfull is tag,dev/root is my fs wich i want to backup,-m ffile mean complete and -t is tag,-d is the backup device group

after this i did

```
backup -i -v -t mytb1 -c demand
```

Works ok but..where is the output?
Thanks

Comment: Isn't it documented in the man page?

Comment: Somehow it seems to me that the statements "This backup command works OK" and "I have no idea *where* it backed up my files" go together like "I just bought a beautiful (and very expensive) suit of clothes" and "In fact, it's so transcendent that I can't even see it (or feel it)."

Comment: It's been a while, but doesn't it try to output to mag tape by default, so maybe `/dev/nrst0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found,those command are a little difficult and no manpages(on AT&T unix was sold separately!).
My goal was a backup of /dev/root(is the / )
on separate disk(0s1 mount on /usr)
First i edit /etc/bkup/bkreg.tab
and put this line

```
ff1212:/:/dev/root::demand::ffile::0::/usr3:type=dir:ff200::
```

Then i run

```
backup -v -i -o  /dev/root -c demand
```

Works fine!